# TikZ "mark connection node" only works for first node mark

Tags: tikz-pgf

The following code fails with the error
`` ! Package pgf Error: No shape named `B' is known. `` There is no error for `mark connection node=A`. Seemingly the only accessible node is the one defined first. Is this expected?

```latex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[decoration={
    markings,
    mark=at position .33 with {\node [draw] (A) {A};},
    mark=at position .66 with {\node [draw] (B) {B};},
    mark connection node=B,
  }
  ]
  \draw [help lines] grid (3,2);
  \draw decorate { (0,0) -- (3,2) };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: And if I add a "phantom node" `\node (B) {};` in the body of the `tikzpicture`, i.e. right before the grid, then code works AND the mark node breaks the path (the behavior I wanted originally). Strange.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Surprisingly, naming the two nodes with the same name, works.

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[decoration={
    markings,
    mark connection node=A,
    mark=at position .33 with {\node [draw] (A) {A};},
    mark=at position .66 with {\node [draw] (A) {B};}, % <<< name it with "A"
  }
  ]
  \draw [help lines] grid (3,2);
  \draw decorate { (0,0) -- (3,2) };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

*Update:* I've reported this to `pgf-tikz`, see https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/issues/1024.